Update default location of storing svg file when importing vector asset in Android studio
Previously, when importing a vector asset in android studio, svg files by default get stored in drawable folder, but now each time I have to manually select the location in pop up in android studio, otherwise it shows option to store in src/main/res/color

I want to make it default for main src/main/res, does anyone else also faced this issue and found a way to update this setting ??

You should add SVG files by the "Vector Asset" menu item as shown here by Right click on your module's layout directory.

